# no corruption! I need help

Tags: terraria-console

I have went from left to right, up to down and my world only has jungle, beach, crimpson, and snowy biomes. I had that world since 2019 and worked so hard on it, i really don't want to make a new world and probably have the same problem. Is it possible to bring those orbs with you into another world, if so please help me.

Answer (score -1):

Each terraria world will only have one evil, either corruption or crimson. If you want corruption stuff I believe you need to make a new world, but use the same character. In 1.4 there is a way to choose which evil you want.